# Visualforce onChange not always rerendering

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page with a select box that fire off an action that re-renders a section of the page based on the selection. This works fine when you select any of the other options in the list. However, when you try to select the original option, the section that was suppose to re-render still reflects the last value. Again, every value except the original results in the expected behavior. Why wont it fire when I select the original?

I am afraid I cant past a code sample, it would take a bit to cull through any proprietary information, sorry.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to get a decent answer without some sample code.  I've used onchange rerenderers with VF pages (tied to a `SELECT` element) without issue.  If you can boil it down to a very basic sample and post that here you'd get a faster and probably better response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk of shame time. I had flag that checked whether the value coming back from the page was different then the one stored in salesforce. This was done to avoid unnecessary db calls but it was causing the section not to re-render when the drop-down was changed to its original value.

Comment: You may want to consider accepting your own response as answer, or deleting your question. That way everyone can see your problem has been resolved.

Comment: Don't delete the question.  There are some good answers in here that are sometimes the cause of rerender not working that will be useful for others.

Comment: I voted to close the question because the question isn't specific and as you've found it was some other issue with your code causing the problem, so keeping this question/answer here won't really help any other StackExchange users in the future, which is one of the main purposes of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code this would be tricky to solve, but perhaps the easiest solution here would be to have a dummy value in the first slot, saying "--select--" or similar, with null as it's value.

Comment: I thought of something along those lines but the section that gets re-rendered has to come in with a default value matching the select box. The ux would break down.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is an error occurring and it that is why it doesn't change.  Do you have an apex:pageMessages tag on the page?  If not add that and it could give you some insight into the actual error.

You might need to add an [actionRegion](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm) to narrow down what is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you don't have `immediate="true"` set on you action, as that skips all setters in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had difficulty with onchange and Internet explorer...it simply doesn't pick up the event.  I used onmouseup instead and had better luck.